# Data with Revision/Version (Versioning) History?

Tags: data.gov, weather, finance, uses-of-open-data, us-census

I'm looking for data set with entry values being corrected, and those corrections are documented with previously incorrect values available as well. This can be in the form of errata, diff files, or old and new versions of the same data set. Ideally, I would prefer data set consisting of numerical/ categorical values that can be used by simple machine learning algorithms like logistic regression. The more the better.

Comment: Wikipedia and GitHub store revision history. Both have APIs, data dumps, BigQuery tables.

Comment: Does Wikipedia have any 'data' data?

Comment: They have tables and infoboxes. Not sure if Wikidata stores revisions. But every WP page has "View history" pages with older revisions of in-text tabulated data.

Answer (score 1):

The [Open-APC data](https://github.com/OpenAPC/openapc-de/tree/master/data) consists of datasets

> [...] on fees paid for Open Access journal articles by Universities and Research Society Funds [...]

[Source](https://github.com/OpenAPC/openapc-de)

The data is freely available and has the GitHub versioning and the GitHub API.